# PNG Image Not Displaying on Server

Tags: html

I uploaded an image to my web server just like all the images are. I created it in Photoshop and exported to a .png. The image resides under The code is `src=""` But the browser shows that the image does not exist. I've set permissions to 0777, I've changed the image path, tried a different image in the same path to confirm it's reading the path right, and the image will just not show. You can view the link here, it will show nothing

EDIT: This is what the image is suppose to look like
EDIT: Removed links for privacy

Comment: I see a 20px x 20px transparent png

Comment: Firefox tells me that your image cannot be displayed because it contains errors. Assuming the image can be displayed on your local computer, my guess is that it somehow got corrupted in transit. How did you upload it to your server?

Comment: Chrome shows this image

Comment: @Brian Uploading using Filezilla. It's been working fine for a while, I'm not sure why it would all of a sudden go corrupt.

Comment: What did you use to set the permissions to `0777`?  Are you sure whatever it is uses octal or maybe it should be the decimal `777`.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Using filezilla to change permission. It shows 0777 in the file explorer under the "Permissions" column, but right click and "change permissions", it shows 777. Either way, it's set at 777.

Comment: It looks like your image is corrupt in some way.  It's returning a 200 OK response from the server.  I'd try taking the source PNG, opening it in some image editor, resaving it, and reuploading it.

Comment: Tried using paint, saved it and reuploaded. Still nothing.. I may be contacting GoDaddy soon...

Answer (score 1):

You forgot " at the end.
It should be like this:

```
src="img/SccBridgeLogo.png"
```

OR

Try adding / at the beginning of the path, that should tell the browser to search from index directory.

```
src="/img/SccBridgeLogo.png"
```

Note this only works if you are running on a site, running from index.html in browser will return in

```
File:////
```

Comment: I have the " in the code, just didn't put it for the example.

Comment: Let me ask you, is you index.html file in the same directory where IMG folder is? If its in one folder up than you should type
src="../img/SccBridgeLogo.png".I think that's what would help you!

Comment: Index.php is located in the root, img is one folder down. `/img/SccBridgeLogo.png` Look at the site to see structure. Changing src to another image in the same directory will display the image. For example `/img/loading.gif` will display.

Comment: Try re-uploading the picture and see will it work, for me it doesn't seems to show any picture? Have you misspelled the name?

Comment: I've reuploaded several time. See the link in the OP. It is spelled correctly, and has the right path.

Comment: I don't know than... It might be corrupted or something... but what I get is only a gray border, 32x32. Which means picture might be there but can't load.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the picture tag for fallbacks and came across this issue at that point.

This use to work fine

`<img src="images/netgraph-logo.png" alt="NetGraph Logo">`

After adding the *picture* tag

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="images/netbob-logo.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="images/netbob-logo.png" type="image/png">
  <img src="./images/netbob-logo.png" alt="NetBob Logo">
</picture>
```

In my case I was able to go down one folder from the root folder, therefore "**./**" preceding the rest of the url worked fine. You may need to back up several folders instead though, so be sure you are using the correct type of path.